# Why is my door on top of bricks?

Tags: doors, basement, garage, door-frame

I have a door leading from my basement, (finished, livable, but still rough compared to the rest of the house) to the drive-under garage. This door isn't to code in the slightest: it's an interior door rather than a 20-minute fire door as is required for garage-entry; it's a hollow core door with the top cut off and open; and it has lots of space to gap and draft. As such I want to replace it with something more appropriate and code-compliant.

However, some problems arise when trying to do so, namely that the door is 78" tall rather than the standard 80". It's also elevated on a row of bricks, which serves as a tripping hazard. I would like to remove those bricks to fit a standard, code-compliant door. What purpose do those bricks serve, and what risk might I introduce by removing them? Can I remove them? Should I?

I haven't found anything related to any code-compliance with regards to an elevated door. The only purpose I can think that the bricks might serve is flood-prevention.

[image: Door in Question]

Comment: I have the same thing and I wondered also why it is until it rained really bad one day and all the neighbors got water in their basements and I didn’t. In any case, I wouldn’t remove it just yet, it looks like a perfect illustration of “Chesterton’s fence”

Comment: I agree, it's probably there for flood control.  Also be careful when trying to make basements habitable rooms, you need to meet egress requirements.

Comment: instead of removing the bricks you can make a platform to reduce the tripping hazard

Comment: @kioleanu of course not yet, which is why I'm asking what I might be missing. We've had some heavy rains and I've not even seen water in the garage yet, let alone the basement.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Not using any part of the basement as a bedroom, so the egresses I have currently are sufficient.

Comment: @ratchetfreak There's much more concern than just the tripping hazard.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in many comments and other answers, those blocks (cinder blocks, or CMUs - cement masonry units) are, at a minimum, providing flood protection for your basement. It may not be *perfect* protection, but would certainly reduce the rate at which water will enter your basement.

Since they're serving a purpose and removing them would, generally, be not the best idea, here are a couple of possibilities:

1. Order a custom sized fire-rated door that will fit your 78" opening. This is likely going to be fairly expensive, but will get you what you want.
2. After removing the existing door & frame, carefully mark the CMUs about 2-1/2" down from their top surface and cut them down. This will give you the height to install a standard 80" door (including a little bit of wiggle room with that extra 1/2" to ensure the door is level & square so it swings/closes correctly). It will also retain the majority of the flood protection that those blocks are providing *and* reduce the trip hazard of the threshold, thus giving you the best of all three worlds.

Comment: Would second keeping the blocks.  We had a house and for over ten years the basement stayed dry.  We finish the basement and a couple years after the drain backup during heavy rain.  Not nice.  You said no water after recent rains yet, main word is yet.

Answer (score 1):

Many houses are designed with the garage / basement floor lower than the house floor. This means you get a step down.

However, it seems yours is just designed as a flood barrier. If you remove it then you take the risk of a future flood - perhaps from a leaking washing machine etc